# OpenPose for Thousands of Video Processing

Tags: python, openpose

I am working on pose estimation for hands and body only using OpenPose (https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose).

I have thousands of videos in my dataset but I can not be able to run OpenPose on each video individually. Because I think I run out of gpu memory which I have GeForce RTX 2080 Ti. I have reduced the frame count of each video to 16 but no luck.

Is there any efficient way that I can extract pose coordinates of hands and body estimations through OpenPose for 20 000 videos?

-- Edit --

I am simply using the following command for each video;

```
./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --image_dir *some_vid-image_location*  --hand --write_json *destination_pose_location*
```

-- Edit --

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it work with 1 or 2 videos? what's the error when you try more?

Comment: Maybe it's they way you cal them, are you opening all the videos at once? be sure you close one video after using it  and also make sure you don't open a video before it's necessary => I don't think the question is related to `openPose` but on your workflow. could you please show your code?

Comment: There is no error, the computer just freezes.

Comment: and has it worked with just 1 or 2 videos?

Comment: yes it has worked with 30-40 videos